# How to add custom validation error message adjacent to input fields in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

My Code in View Page(views/session/new.html.erb) :

```
< %= form_for(:session, :url => sessions_path) do |f| %>

          <%= f.label :email, 'Username'%>
          <%= f.text_field :email %>

          <%= f.label :password %>
          <%= f.password_field :password %>

          <%= f.submit  'Login'%>
          <%= link_to 'Forgot Your Password?', new_password_reset_path >
< % end %>
```

I have written proper validation codes in my model file.
But I want that on Submit, the validation errors should pop up at the adjacent to the fields rather than at the top of the Page.

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're inclined to use Rails' built-in server side validations, you can check for whether validation errors exist, then print them if they do:

```
<%= form_for(:session, :url => sessions_path) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :email, 'Username'%>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
  <% if f.object.errors[:email] %>
    <%= f.object.errors[:email].join(", ") %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
  <% if f.object.errors[:password] %>
    <%= f.object.errors[:password].join(", ") %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit 'Login'%>
  <%= link_to 'Forgot Your Password?', new_password_reset_path >

<% end %>
```

Note a few things:

First, because you're passing a *symbol*, rather than an *object* in your form, you'll need to access the object's attributes from within the `form_for` block by invoking `f.object`.

Second, because some fields may yield *more* than one validation error, you'll want to print them out in sequence. Using Ruby's `join` method can help you concatenate these in a coherent manner.

**UPDATE**:

If you want the errors to render directly beside the corresponding text field, you'll need to apply some CSS. Clearly, it's recommended that a stylesheet be used to for this, but in the interest of simplicity, here's of an example of how this *might* be rendered using inline styling:

```
<%= f.text_field :email, :address, :style => "display: inline-block; float: left;" %>
<% if f.object.errors[:email] %>
  <span style="display: inline-block; float: left;">
    <%= f.object.errors[:email].join(", ") %>
  </span>
<% end %>
<div style="clear: left;"></div>
```

Comment: I could get the last line but my doubt is where to render those error messages and how to place them exactly adjacent to my Text Fields. I must be dumb enough to ask, but Please Care to reply.

Comment: You'll need to apply some CSS to get this working. Try applying `display: inline-block; float: left;` to both the the text field _and_ whatever's wrapping the error text.

Comment: Please see the update to my answer for a potential method of formatting as you've specified.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with something like this:

```
<%= form_for(:session, :url => sessions_path) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :email, 'Username' %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
  <%= f.object.errors[:email].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:email] %>
<% end %>
```

I reckon you'll figure out the rest.

Comment: I could get the last line but my doubt is where to render those error messages and how to place them exactly adjacent to my Text Fields. 
I must be dumb enough to ask, but Please Care to reply.

Comment: You can use normal HTML and CSS along with Ruby-specific tags. So you can for example put the label, text field and error (if any) in one <p> tag and this way make sure they are shown in one line. You may need to add some CSS to style errors, so perhaps put the error text in some <span class="error"> and style it accordingly in your stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the values of error messages of different model attributes with `errors` hash like `errors[:some_attribute_name]`. As long as your custom validators store error message in the right model attribute, you can probably do something like this.

```rb
< %= form_for(:session, :url => sessions_path) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :email, 'Username'%>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
  <%= f.object.errors[:email] %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
  <%= f.object.errors[:password] %>

  <%= f.submit  'Login'%>
  <%= link_to 'Forgot Your Password?', new_password_reset_path >
< % end %>
```

I'll let you worry about how the error is displayed beside the form and stuff. :)